# how group by clause is working in oracle sql

Tags: oracle10g

I have a code like below

```
WITH mytable AS
 (SELECT '10' AS n
    FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '20'
    FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '20'
    FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '30'
    FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '20'
    FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '100'
    FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL
    FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '200'
    FROM DUAL)
SELECT   n
 FROM mytable
GROUP BY n
```

I am getting output as like below
         output
         -----
         NULL
         100
         200
         20
         10
         30

why the NULL value is first?

Please explain me why the 100 next and 200 so on..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default order when you unite subqueries unless you specify an ORDER BY (which you can put only after the last subquery).

You were just lucky to get such a result (however I got the same). Maybe Oracle processes rows in some way which puts NULLS first but you cannot bank on this.

However, if there are NULLS values in a column from an ORDER BY clause Oracle has specific rules:

> When SELECT performs a sort using ORDER BY, it treats any values that
>   it might find to be NULL as “greater than” any other value. In other
>   words, when you sort by a numeric datatype column, and that column
>   contains NULL values, the NULL values will sort as being greater than
>   all NOT NULL values in the list. The same is true for character
>   datatypes and date datatypes.